# Theorem $17$, Chapter $3$ (Marcus' Number Fields): Every ideal in a Dedekind domain is generated by at most two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

I understand that similar questions have been asked before, but I am looking for an explanation of certain steps in Marcus' proof of the same, in Theorem $17$, Chapter $3$ of *Number Fields.* I shall paraphrase the proof slightly for convenience.

**Theorem.** Let $I$ be an ideal in a Dedekind domain $R$, and let $\alpha$ be any nonzero
element of $I$. Then there exists $β ∈ I$ such that $I = (α, β)$.

---

> *Proof.* It is sufficient to construct $\beta\in R$ such that $I = \gcd((\alpha),(\beta))$.

1. I know that $\gcd(J,J') = J+J'$, so we expect $I = (\alpha) + (\beta)$ to imply $I = (\alpha,\beta)$. Indeed, $(\alpha) + (\beta) = (\alpha,\beta)$ follows from definitions, as $(\alpha) + (\beta) = R\alpha + R\beta = (\alpha,\beta)$.

> Let $P_1^{n_1}P_2^{n_2}\ldots P_r^{n_r}$ be the prime decomposition of $I$, where $P_i$ are distinct. Then, $(\alpha)$ is divisible by all $P_i^{n_i}$. Let $Q_1,\ldots, Q_s$ denote the other primes (if any) which divide $(\alpha)$. We must construct $\beta$ such that none of the $Q_j$ divide $(β)$, and for each $i$, $P_i^{n_i}$ is the exact power of $P_i$ dividing $(β)$. Equivalently, $$\beta\in \bigcap_{i=1}^r (P_i^{n_i} - P_i^{n_i+1}) \cap \bigcap_{j=1}^s (R - Q_j).$$

2. Why must we construct such a $\beta$? I know that $A|B$ if and only if $B\subset A$, but I do not see an immediate contradiction.

> This can be accomplished via the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Fix $β_i ∈ P_i^{n_i} − P_{i}^{n_i+1}$ (which is necessarily nonempty by unique factorization) and let $β$ satisfy the congruences $$\beta\equiv \beta_i \bmod P_i^{n_i+1}, \quad i = 1, \ldots, r$$
> $$\beta\equiv 1 \bmod Q_j, \quad j= 1,\ldots,s$$
> (To show that such a $β$ exists we have to show the powers of the $P_i$ and the $Q_j$
> are pairwise co-maximal: that the sum of any two is $R$. This is easy to verify if one
> interprets the sum as the greatest common divisor.)

3. I understand the Chinese Remainder Theorem in the following form: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ be pairwise relatively prime ideals in $R$. Then,
   $$R\left/\bigcap_{i=1}^n I_i\right. \cong R/I_1 \times \ldots \times R/I_n$$
   and the canonical map $r + \bigcap_{i=1}^n I_i \mapsto (r+ I_1, \ldots, r+I_n)$ is a ring isomorphism. How does this help us construct the required $\beta$? Moreover, what does congruence modulo an ideal mean? My guess is that $a \equiv b \bmod I$ if and only if $a-b \in I$. Even if this is true, I have trouble seeing where the congruences in Marcus' proof come from.

I would appreciate any details and explanations. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KCd Yes! We just take the minimum of the exponents instead.

Comment: For the 3rd question: every $\gamma \in \mathfrak p^n - \mathfrak p^{n+1}$ has $\mathfrak p^n \mid (\gamma)$ and $\mathfrak p^{n+1} \nmid (\gamma)$, so $\mathfrak p^n$ is the highest power of $\mathfrak p$ dividing $(\gamma)$. Show for every $\gamma' \equiv \gamma \bmod \mathfrak p^{n+1}$ that $\mathfrak p^n$ is also the highest power of $\mathfrak p$ dividing $(\gamma')$.  When you use this idea for several prime ideals together (by CRT) you can get a single $\beta$ with specified divisibility by a finite set of different prime ideals.

Comment: @KCd For the second question, the observation that the $\gcd$ of two ideals is just the exponent-wise minimum helped; however (i) is it clear that $P_i^{n_i+1}$ does not divide $(\alpha)$? (ii) if $P_i^{n_i}$ is the exact power of $P_i$ dividing $(\alpha)$, then I don't see why we need $P_i^{n_i}$ to be the exact power of $P_i$ dividing $(\beta)$, for the minimum of the two exponents will just be $n_i$. Thanks.

Comment: It is *not* clear (or even reasonable to expect) that $P_i^{n_i+1}$ does not divide $(\alpha)$, so your premise (ii) is irrelevant. By CRT we can create $\beta$ where $P_i^{n_i}$ is the highest power of $P_i$ dividing $(\beta)$.

Comment: @KCd Here's what I've tried for the 3rd question: Let $\gamma\in P^n - P^{n+1}$ and $\gamma' \equiv\gamma \bmod P^{n+1}$. Then, $\gamma' = \gamma + x$ for some $x\in P^{n+1}$. So, $(\gamma') = (\gamma + x) \subset (\gamma) + (x) \subset (\gamma) + P^{n+1} = P^nJ + P^{n+1}$, for some ideal $J$, where $J$ doesn't have any power of $P$ as a prime factor. As a result, $(\gamma') \subset P^n(J + P)$, so $P^n| (\gamma')$. If $P^{n+1}$ divided $(\gamma')$, we'd have $(\gamma') = P^{n+1} K$ for some ideal $K$, so that $P^{n+1} K \subset P^n (J+P)$. Could you help me find a contradiction?

Comment: That $(\gamma') \subset P^n$ can be explained more easily: since $\gamma \in P^n$, $\gamma' \in \gamma + P^{n+1} \subset P^n + P^{n+1} \subset P^{n+1}$. If $P^{n+1} \mid (\gamma')$ then $\gamma' \equiv 0 \bmod P^{n+1}$, so $\gamma \equiv 0 \bmod P^{n+1}$, but $P^{n+1} \nmid (\gamma)$. So $P^{n+1} \nmid (\gamma')$.